# SSL, Hosting, Redirection of multiple ccTLDs domains

Tags: ssl, redirect

We have a domain "abc.com" with our application being hosted at the subdomain with SSL support - "https://cc.abc.com" where cc is the country code

We have bought addition new ccTLDs "abc.com.cc", "abc.cc" which we would like to redirect to "https://cc.abc.com" but we would like to have SSL for these new domains too.

Do we have to buy SSL for both the ccTLDs ? and regarding the hosting and redirection, how do we do this ? setup a webserver for these new domains ? Do we require multiple webservers ? or just one webserver and host both ssl enabled virtual hosts there and enable redirection ? Can i do multiple ssl hosted on a loadbalancer and do the ssl termination for both these domains ? or do we need separate loadbalancers and webserver ?

Thanks
Shankar.S

Comment: If you want users to be able to access these domains via HTTPS, then of course you need SSL certificates for them. And no, this does not require multiple web server, you can handle all of that on one machine, if you like.

Comment: You are asking multiple questions here. The question about needing a certificate for the site you redirect from is clearly a duplicate. As for how to do this exactly: you can have multiple hosts on the same server both with HTTP and HTTPS but how you exactly do this depends on the server or load-balancer.